# How to update a counter field from a different table in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have 3 tables in MySQL `ParkIn{ parkin_id,InTime}` ,`ParkOut{parkout_id,OutTime}` and `Counter{ Counter_ID, Counter}`. 
Everytime there is an Insert in the Parkin table I need the Counter column to add 1 to its previous value and whenever there is a Insert in the ParkOut table I need the counter column to subtract 1. The counter table doesnt necessarily have to insert new lines everytime but rather just keep updating the counter value.

Comment: oh good that's really nice. Do you have a question?

Comment: I am not able to create a trigger for this. Not able to set up the counter in the update of the trigger.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify. How many rows are in your `Counter` table? It seems you want your `Counter.Counter` value to be updated each time there's an insert to one of the other tables. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing this the hard way.

You can do

```
      SELECT (parkin.rowcount - parkout.rowcount) Counter
        FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) rowcount FROM ParkIn) parkin
        JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) rowcount FROM ParkOut) parkout
```

when you need the value you described. You can trust that databases are made to do this kind of thing.

If you really want the illusion that you have a Counter table, you can create a view.

```
      CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Counter AS
      SELECT (parkin.rowcount - parkout.rowcount) Counter
        FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) rowcount FROM ParkIn) parkin
        JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) rowcount FROM ParkOut) parkout
```

Your Counter table, as you described it in your question, is known as a "materialized view" in the DBMS trade. It's "materialized" because it's an actual table that you actually maintain in real time.  I am suggesting using an ordinary view, not a materialized view, to solve your problem.